# Setting up front end data persistance on Laravel & Vue 3 & Pinia

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, pinia

I'm working on a development using PHP Laravel 8 and JS Vue 3, and need to persist data in my main Pinia data store, so I downloaded and NPM installed Prazdevs's [pina-plugin-persistedstate](https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate) plugin, but I cannot get it to work, mainly because I don't think my setup is correct. Here's the code:
On resources\js\app.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia, mapStores } from 'pinia'
import { usemainStore } from './stores/main'
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'

const app = {
    components: {
    },

    data() {
        return {
        }
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapStores(usemainStore)
    },

    methods: {
    },

    mounted() {
    },

    watch: {
    }
}

const myApp = createApp(app)

myApp
    .use(createPinia())
    .use(piniaPluginPersistedstate)
    .mount("#app")
```

On resources\js\main.js:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const usemainStore = defineStore('main', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            counter: 1,
        }
    },

    persist: true,

    getters: {
    },

    actions: {
    },

})
```

An finally on resources\js\components\layouts\basic.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Counter: {{ $root.mainStore.counter }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
    },

    data() {
        return {
        }
    },

    methods: {
    },

    mounted() {
    },
}
</script>
```

Webpack's NPM console shows no errors, but the Chrome Dev Console shows the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'persist')
> at app.js:116043:18
> at Object.use (app.js:11677:21)
> at ./resources/js/app.js (app.js:67371:138)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:116338:42)
> at app.js:116661:89
> at **webpack_require**.O (app.js:116375:23)
> at app.js:116666:53
> at app.js:116668:12

Even before adding the persistedstate plugin, the setup didn't feel right, but it worked fine and I can write and read from the store, no hassle. I've tried many possible code combinations, and the best I could get was no errors on the Dev Console, but the Counter value (manually changed via Chrome Console) is not persisted.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry @joels, I didn't...  : (